# Get pageviews for certain URL from Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a site which have some articles. My caching server obstacle the natural readings counting and I want to retrieve the real pageviews from Google Analytics, via Javascript.

How could I get this number for each article?

Through https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ I've successful built the query I need and I found the URL I need is something like that:

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:[SITE_ID]&start-date=2005-01-01&end-date=today&metrics=ga:pageviews&dimensions=ga:pagePath&filters=ga:pagePath==[PAGE_PATH]&access_token=ya29.SwLatBgi9WnVYKKiIeHpJEmAg--UJ4JTGoWrJZR4sw1paPpNltwVwzoaZ05aDkFudIFeWg

But how have I to do to build this URL directly from each article's page?

Comment: Do you want page views for your articles ??

Comment: I think you will need to use the https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/  in order to refresh your access tokens.  Are you looking for a widget of sorts to display page views on your pages?  I developed a 3rd party reporting service: http://www.embeddedanalytics.com.  We could provide you widget in which you simply pass the page path.  We do all of the API calls on your behalf.

Comment: I need to get the count of pageviews and use in the site layout, replacing a text placeholder in the page. How I could generate the token through js?

Comment: for certain url you can use filter `  'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/page-slug', if your target is a specific url . if you want page views for all urls. you should go for In PHP I did something like `data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    $start_date,
    $end_date,
    'ga:pageviews' );`  but still not clear what you need .

Comment: I have a site where the standard Google Analytics tracks my users. In some pages (single blog articles) I need to retrieve the total pageviews for the URL of the article.